# Размещение Layout на экране

Tags: android, android-layout

Здравствуйте! Мне нужно разместить на экране много компонентов `LinearLayout(200,50)`, но когда пытаюсь, они начинают перекрывать друг друга, размера экрана не хватает. Пытался разместить каждый  друг в друге, но все равно не получается. Есть ли какой то способ реализовать это? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 4):

Достаточно просто засунуть ваш `LinearLayout` в `ScrollView` [вот так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4057224/375929).

Роман отчасти прав, однако, если ваш контент - статический (бишь, известен сразу, ничего не надо добавлять "на ходу"), не надо `ListView` - он очень, очень тяжелый и навороченный (адаптер, переиспользование вьюшек), вам не нужен весь этот оверхэд (overhead).

Answer (score 2):

Используйте для этого **ListView**. Вот вам пример: [ListView в Android: Кастомизация списков](http://habrahabr.ru/post/133575/).